# Can I install IIS 6 or 7 on a Windows XP machine?

Tags: iis, windows-xp

I've heard that this isn't possible because you need to have the Windows Server OS installed, but that seems kind of ridiculous because how would you set up a local development environment?  Anyway, curious if this is possible.

Comment: MS would probably like you to use a more recent operating system to do your development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exlcuding Windows Server OS', IIS6 needs [Windows XP Pro](http://www.ehow.com/how_2272270_configure-iis-6-windows-xp.html) 64-bit and IIS7 needs Vista.

A thread on the [Microsoft IIS website](http://forums.iis.net/t/1156371.aspx) also says you can, as 64-bit WinXP Pro comes with IIS6.

Comment: There is no 64bit requirement.

Comment: Please support your claim about IIS6 installation on XP 32-bit by appropriate link.

Comment: @Brandon: Windows XP 64-bit is essentially Windows 2003 kernel. Windows XP 32-bit is not.

Comment: @EFraim, I know. I had it written as 64-bit, but per jsights comment, I removed that part of the answer. Then when you asked for a link I realized I was right the first time. I guess I skipped the part of your comment where you specified 32-bit.

Comment: @McChrister: It has been downvoted for being factually inaccurate at the moment it was downvoted. Currently the downvote was released.

Comment: @Brandon - Thanks... I didn't realize that IIS6 was available for XP64.  XP64 is even weirder than I thought (and in a good way)! :)

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://iisanswers.com/IISFAQ.htm) says you cannot.

EDIT: Clarification: kernel-wise Windows XP 64-bit is 2003 for all intents and IIS related purposes.

Comment: It tells the whole tale exactly. Windows XP is XP and 2003 is 2003, whatever MS says XP 64-bit is really 2003. (See kernel version)

Comment: @MrChrister: should I ask the same?

Answer (score 1):

There are also some hacky methods to install IIS5 on XP Home, but I don't think that there are hacks for IIS6 on XP 32bit (thought 64 bit XP apparently has IIS6 available):

- [Running IIS on Windows XP Home Edition?](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020118.htm)
- [AdamV.com (looks similar)](http://adamv.com/dev/articles/iis-on-xp-home/)

This is not supported by MS.  If you are just wanting to test locally, the dev server built in to VS is recommended (or [Cassini](http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx) - previous versions are available as well).  If you are wanting to serve primarily non-asp.net content, then there are lots of other popular web servers available that will work on XP Home (Apache, etc).

Comment: Yeah, thats true.  I read the first answer and made a false assumption (that the first answer was relevant) then forgot the 6 requirement. :)  I've clarified my answer.