# Can IIS 6 in Windows XP x64 have multiple sites like Windows Server 2003?

Tags: iis, windows-xp

I've heard there is a restriction that you can only allow IIS to set up one site on XP x64 despite the fact it is IIS 6, which wouldn't usually have that restriction if running on Windows Server 2003.  Can anyone confirm this is true, and if it is, does anyone know of a workaround?  This is a development machine and it would be nice to have it mirror our production machines as much as possible and also so I can familiarize myself with the configuration without mucking with the production instances.

Comment: And it's a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180029/can-i-install-iis-6-or-7-on-a-windows-xp-machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot.  https://serverfault.com/questions/39077/running-multiple-website-on-windows-xp-64